# Undefined index for delete page

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a delete option for a table which is directly getting data from the mysql database. I have a function to display the table and want to add 'delete' button with each category. Somehow I get Undefined index for 'cat_id' which is 'category id'according to my table.

this is the function that i am using 
function dispcategories() {
        include ('connection.php');

```
    $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM categories");
    echo '';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
        echo "<table class='category-table'>";
        echo "<tr><td class='main-category' colspan='2'>".$row['category_title']."</td></tr>
              <tr><td><a href='deletecategory.php?id=".$row['cat_id'].";? >'>delete</a></td></tr>;"; 
          dispsubcategories($row['cat_id']);

        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

and this is what i have on my delete page

```
$id = $_GET['cat_id'];
$del = mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM `categories` WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: could you show us the column fields of your table? it seems cat_id doesn't exists in their table or maybe it has a different name.

Comment: thankyou for the reply, i have the field directly made in my database table with the name cat_id

Comment: 1) you're open to SQL injection and should address immediately. 2) what's the rendered URI of delete? does it look like `?id=XX`?

Comment: @treyBake yes that's what i get in my url but $_GET doesnot seem to be getting this id

Answer (score 0):

Remove `;?>` from `href='deletecategory.php?id=".$row['cat_id'].";?>'` and also you don't need semi-colon here `</tr>;`

Then your url is `deletecategory.php?id=xx` so you should have `$_GET['id']` instead of `$_GET['cat_id']`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but my query still fails after these changes

Comment: $id=$_GET['id'];
$del=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM `categories` WHERE id='$id'");
if(!$del){
 echo 'failed';
}

Comment: So you use `categories.cat_id` to delete `categories.id`, is it expected?

Comment: yes, i want to delete the specific id that is selected

Answer (score -1):

Try to modify your code as follows

```
$select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_title, cat_id FROM categories");

    echo "<table class='category-table'>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) {
    if(!isset($row['cat_id'])
         continue;

    echo "<tr>
              <td class='main-category' colspan='2'>".$row['category_title']."</td>
              <td><a href='deletecategory.php?id=".$row['cat_id']."'>delete</a></td>
         </tr>;"; 
      // dispsubcategories($row['cat_id']); // I don't know the use of this but try to comment it

}
    echo "</table>";
```

Regards

Comment: this code is working good thanks for that,because it takes the id correctly in the url, the problem seems to be with the query on the delete page which is failing $id=$_GET['id'];
$del=mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM `categories` WHERE id='$id'");

Comment: Assigne the query to a variable: 
$query = "DELETE FROM categories WHERE id=$id";
$select = mysqli_query($con, $query);

Comment: @DanielLuna that query is open to SQL injection ...

Comment: @user1234 is that field nullable?

Comment: @treyBake no the field is not nullable

Comment: @user1234 then cat_id should never be unset

Comment: @user1234 do you still have problems with the query?

Comment: @DanielLuna no i solved it, I had foreign keys in my table which was causing the query to fail, I did the cascade on delete in the tables and it worked fine, thanks a lot for your help